# Firebase database getValue issue

Tags: android, exception, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getvalue

My app gives the following error:
**com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String**

This error occurs on in the line: mGame = dataSnapshot.getValue(Game.class)
Here is my code:

```
//create datarefence of only 1 game namely the current game
    specificGameRef =mDatabase.child("games").child(-KhmBnF9vTLJSgNBcPqE);
    specificGameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            mGame =dataSnapshot.getValue(Game.class);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Here is my json code from the firebase database:
[image]

If someone could help me found my error, thanks.

**EDIT: Game class:**

```
public class Game {
//firebase
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

FirebaseUser user;
User mUser;
private String creatorName;
private String key;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private int clockHours;
private int clockMinutes;
private int durationMin;
private int durationMax;
private String creatorId;


public Game() //An empty constructor for datastorage of Firebase
{

}

public Game(String creatorId) {


    this.creatorId = creatorId;
    key = getKey();
    day = getDay();
    month = getMonth();
    year = getYear();
    clockHours = getClockHours();
    clockMinutes = getClockMinutes();
    durationMin = getDurationMin();
    durationMax = getDurationMax();
```

}

**EDIT: User class**

```
public class User {
//firebase authentification system
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

String userId;
String mUsername;
String email;
int age;
int stars;
int badReputation;
String gender;
int birthYear;
int birthMonth;
int birthDay;

public User()
{

}

public User(String userId,String mUsername,String email) {

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    this.userId = userId;
    this.mUsername = mUsername;
    age = getAge();
    stars = 0;
    this.email=email;
    badReputation = 0;
    gender = "";
}
```

On top of that, I have this other class where a dataSnapshot.getValue of a User class. And it works perfectly, what is up with that?? Here is the code:

```
public void retrieveUser()
{
    //create datarefence of only 1 user namely the current user
    DatabaseReference specificCreatorRef =mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid());
    specificCreatorRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //Now retrieving the current user and putting it in object mUser
            mUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            Log.w(TAGESS, "Print  STARS of current mUSer: " + mUser.getStars());
            creatorGender =mUser.getGender();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

So this last code works perfect, so why does this work and not the DataSnapshot.getValue(Game.class)?
Thanks!

Comment: data type in Game model class might de different from the value you got from dataSnapshot, Please check it once or provide your model class

Comment: What do you mean by the datatype of Game class? I'll add it to the post.

Comment: And the user class?

Comment: Duration is a string, by the way

Comment: Yes duration is converted into a String inside on of the methods of the Game class. I'll add the User class. By the way, I also use datasnapshot.getValue on "users" but there is no issue there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping but after 3 days struggling, I found the line that gave the error. I still don't know why.

In the game class I had some getters and setters, When replacing the setter of clockHours with code that didn't use Integer.parsInt, it worked....!

```
 public void setClockHours(String clockHours){

    this.clockHours = Integer.parseInt(clockHours);
}
```

Thanks anyway for your time